# How to set heapsize of Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Sometimes my intellij will stuck there, so I'd like to increase heapsize for it. And I following instruction here. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/increasing-memory-heap.html  But it doesn't help, because I still see intellij only use 512M as heapsize as following showing, what do I miss ?

jzhang          68196   0.0  0.6  3361244  94944   ??  S     3:35PM   0:02.78 /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -d64 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==14.1.5 -Xmx512m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.0.5 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Cont...

Comment: Windows and mac -> https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827537-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Comment: It doesn't work after I following the link above. One thing confuse me is that I see intellij take around 1G in Mac's activity monitor. But I see it specify -Xmx512. They might not be the same process. The issue is that it takes a long time to import a large project, it just hangs there.

Comment: This works, it really does, so you're modifying the wrong file or doing something else wrong.